# Sending emails to multiple recipients with different content

Tags: php

I need to send mails to multiple recipients notifying about their pending tasks.

This is the array for querying pending tasks for each recipient.

```
$pending = array(
"select * from user WHERE status='processing' and reason!='Out of island'",
"select * from user WHERE status='processing' and reason!='Out of island'", //DGM-HR 
"select * from user WHERE status='new'", //DGM-ITAS
"select * from user WHERE status='processing' and reason='Out of island'", //Manager-HR
"select * from user where CRM_Status='pending'",  //CRM-Eng
"select * from user where OSS_Status='pending'",  //OSS-Eng
"select * from user where BSS_Status='pending'"  //BSS-Eng
);
```

//Retrieve results from each query and pass it to another array. This array is not working.

```
$pending = implode("\r\n", $pending);
$result = array(
mysqli_query($dbcon,$pending)
);
```

//Getting the result and send the mail to relevant recipient. But I haven't set up the recipient part yet.

```
foreach($result as $result1)
{
        if(!$result1) 
        {
            die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($result1 as $count)
            {
                $count= mysqli_num_rows($result1);
                $mail->addAddress('to_mail', 'to'); //Only for single recipient
                $mail->Subject = 'Notification: User Management System';
                $mail->Body    = 'Dear User, <br> <br>You have '.$count.' records which is pending for your approval.<br> Please engage for the relevant tasks.<br><br>';
                $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: mysqli_query() will not assemble results from multiple queries for you. You need to either perform multiple queries or use a single query with a compound WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running multiple queries and asking to DB, just run a general query and filter in your results for faster access. Once you have the arrays for the general query you can do whatever you want